# Join strings on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, maps

I have to print a runner-up point of a championship in python (n = number of scores)

```py
n = int(input())
pontosmap = map(list, input().split())
pontos = list(pontosmap)
pontos.sort()
ptscrt = []
for abc in pontos:
    if abc not in ptscrt:
        ptscrt.append(abc)
ptscrt.sort()
while len(ptscrt)>2:
    ptscrt.pop(0)
ptscrt.pop(1)
res = str(ptscrt)[1:-1]
print (res.replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]",""))
```

I've made this, but when is a result > 10 or a negative number it goes wrong, for example:
input =
`4`
`57 57 -57 57`
expected output:
`-57`
my output:
`-, 5, 7`
I'm resolving this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-second-maximum-number-in-a-list/problem

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. You say you have to print the runner up, but your desired result it `-57`?

Comment: `pontos` is a list of strings, not ints so I think your sort is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisCharley in the above code I believe `pontos` is a list of lists of strings (not that this improves the sort or clarifies anything).

Comment: You do not need to decorate every single line with backticks and line breaks. Just copy and paste the code as-is and put triple backticks above and below.

Comment: @Mark Meyer yes, you are correct.

Comment: Pontos is a list of strings, because on other examples like: 4, 2 6 3 7 it goes correctly

Comment: Did you understand it????

Comment: The link you added to hacker rank show the correct way to get a list of integers: `arr = map(int, input().split())`. It's not clear why you changed that to `map(list, input().split()) `. Also, there's no reason to every convert this to strings for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join:

```
print(“”.join(res.replace("'","").replace("[","").replace("]","")))
```

Comment: Then is the same result: -, 5, 7